# Matlab vs C++ runtime comparison

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization

I am formulating a rather large optimization problem in both Matlab and C++ to compare the calculation time. I would have thought that by converting the code to C++, I would reduce the calculation time for my program, but this is not the case. Is this down to my lack of C++ experience, or can actually Matlab be 6-7 times faster in this specific case? Below, a snippet of my code is provided.

```cpp
/*
    Comnum - int
    ky - int
    numcams - int
    outmat - std::vector<std::vector<bool>>
*/
    array_bool bout(ky);
    auto tt = Clock::now();
    array_int sum(comnum);
    for(int m = 0; m < comnum ; m++){
        //array_bool bout(ky);
        std::fill(bout.begin(),bout.end(),false);

        // Fill is faster than looping as shown below
/*
        for(int l = 0 ; l < ky ; l++)
        {
            bout[l] = false;
        }
*/
        for(int n = 0; n < numcams ; n++){
            int ind = combarr[m][n];
            std::transform(bout.begin(),bout.end(),outmat[ind].begin(),bout.begin(),std::plus<bool>());

            // Transform is faster than looping as shown below
/*
            for(int i = 0 ; i < ky ; i++)
            {
                bout[i] = bout[i] | outmat[ind][i];
            }
*/

        }
        // Looping is faster than using accumulate 
//      sum[m] = std::accumulate(bout.begin(),bout.end(),0);


        sumof = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < ky ; j++)
        {
            if(bout[j] == true) sumof +=1;
        }

        sum[m] = sumof;

    }

    auto ttt = Clock::now();
```

I have provided comments where I have tried to speed up my code. The according Matlab code looks as follows:

CombArr - single matrix
ncams - single

```matlab
t2 = tic; 

for m = 1:length(CombArr)
    bcombs = false(1,ldata);  % Set current combination coverage array to 0

    % Loop through given number of cameras and compute coverage 
    % For given combination (bcombs)
    for n = 1:ncams 
        ind = CombArr(m,n);  
        bcombs(1,1:ldata) = bcombs(1,1:ldata) | b(ind,1:ldata);
    end

    % Compute the sum of covered data points
    sumcurr(m) = single(sum(bcombs(1,1:ldata)));


end
toc(t2)
```

I know this is probably a too long question to post, but I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to why C++ uses about 6 times longer to compute the code?

Comment: Did you enable optimizations for C++ compiler?

Comment: How have you compiled your code? You have compiled your code in release mode, right? Do you have set the optimization level to be 3 (compile option -O3)?

Comment: The logical indexing you are using in MATLAB is optimised (in mysterious ways) which may be inherently quicker than your loop in C++

Comment: combarr[m][n] - code generated by matlab represents matrixes as 1d arrays. its way faster. I doubt just this can cause 6x difference, but i think it is first thing you should consider optimizing. Read about vectorizing loops (i hope i used correct terms, english is not my first language)

Comment: Ah, the people that still think that MATLAB is slow.... MATLAB has JIT compiler and *for some things* its considerably faster than any naive implementation you may do in C. "Early optimization is the root of all evil", and you did indeed, find all this evil! Also, don't tic toc this, profile the code properly (with profiler tool) to see what is fast and what slow

Comment: Use [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) instead of tic/toc.

Comment: My compile code is g++ *.cpp -o ./out

Comment: g++ *.cpp -o out 

Sorry, typed it wrong

Comment: You don't need to compare booleans against true, you know.

Comment: Absolutely, looks much nicer without comparing!

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicated, changing my compiling did it for me. Reduced the computational time by a factor of 10 by using this compilation code:

```
g++ code.cpp -O3 -o test
```

Thank you all, this really helped me!

Comment: Sidenote: Now the computational time is ~2 times faster in C++ than in Matlab.

Comment: Now try to change it back to std::accumulate.

Comment: Approximately the same, 1% slower actually.. Is this unexpected?